# How to print these two elements on same line?

Tags: css, html

How can I display these two page elements on the same line? As they are now, the divs make the elements display on two rows.

```
    <div id="logo-img"><a class="nobk" href="/ai">
<img src="/_/img/logo.gif" alt="Logo"/></a><div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false">
    </div><div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

div is block type, which is always on new line unless it is:

- floating `float: left`
- absolutely positioned `postition: absolute`
- set as inline type `display: inline`

set some of these styles on div.fb-like

Answer (score 1):

you must put your first and second images with float.

Ex:

```
<div class="clrfx" id="logo-img">
<a class="nobk" href="/ai"><img class="fleft" src="/_/img/logo.gif" alt="Logo"/></a>
<div class="fb-like fleft" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div></div>

<style type="text/css">
.clearfix {display: block;}
.fleft{float:left;}
```

I prefer not to use positioning in this case, because it's a little bit tricky for using positioning.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    #logo-img, .fb-like {
        float:left;
    }
</style>
```